# Creating a single colorbar for plots with different data ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to create a graph with three subplots. Each subplot has a different range of data, but I want to create a single colorbar to the right of my plots that can be used for all three subplots. The scaling should be such that the maximum of all of the data corresponds to the maximum of the colorbar and such that the the minimum of all of the data corresponds to the minimum of the colorbar. The three subplots should then be scaled accordingly. Here is my sample code.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter as tk

from math import sin, cos, pi

polar = False
filename = ''

def File_Select():
    global filename
    
    filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

def Plot():
        m = 501
        n = 101
        
        X = np.zeros((m,n))
        Y = np.zeros((m,n))
        DATA_1 = np.zeros((m,n))
        DATA_2 = np.zeros((m,n))
        DATA_3 = np.zeros((m,n))
        
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                X[i][j] = i
                Y[i][j] = j
                DATA_1[i][j] = 5*sin(i*pi/(m-1))
                DATA_2[i][j] = 0.1*cos(1.5*j*pi/(n-1))
                DATA_3[i][j] = 2*sin(5*j*pi/(m-1))+cos(5*i*pi/(n-1))
    
        # Define subplot shapes
        fig = Figure(figsize = (15, 8), dpi = 100, tight_layout=True)
        
        if(m<=n):
            plot1 = fig.add_subplot(131) 
            plot2 = fig.add_subplot(132)  
            plot3 = fig.add_subplot(133) 
        else:
            plot1 = fig.add_subplot(311) 
            plot2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
            plot3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
     
        # Plot contour plots
        plot1.contourf(X, Y, DATA_1, cmap=cm.jet)
        plot1.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
        
        plot2.contourf(X, Y, DATA_2, cmap=cm.jet)
        plot2.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
        
        plot3.contourf(X, Y, DATA_3, cmap=cm.jet)
        plot3.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
        
        graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = root2)   
        graph.draw() 
        graph.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2)
        
        root2.update()

root1 = tk.Tk()
root2 = tk.Tk()

root1.title('Recreate Plots')
root2.title('Contour Plots')

Plot_Button = tk.Button (root1, text='Plot', command=Plot, bg='Green', font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
Plot_Button.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=100,pady=10)

Exit_Button = tk.Button (root1, text='Exit Application', command=root1.quit, bg='orange', font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'))
Exit_Button.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=100,pady=10)

root1.mainloop()

root1.destroy()
root2.destroy()
```

The `m<=n` if-else statement is used to stack the plots top-to-bottom or side-to-side as appropriate.

```
if(m<=n):
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(131) 
    plot2 = fig.add_subplot(132)  
    plot3 = fig.add_subplot(133) 
else:
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(311) 
    plot2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
    plot3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, constrained_layout=True)
dmin = np.inf
dmax = -np.inf
for data in (data1, data2, data3):
    dmin = np.min(np.min(data[:]))
    dmax = np.max(np.max(data[:]))
levels = np.linspace(dmin, dmax, 20)
for ax, data in zip(axs, (data1, data2, data3)):
    pc = ax.contourf(data, levels=levels)
fig.colorbar(pc, ax=axs)
```

Comment: when I run the code that you gave, I get an error with the `ax.contour`  ```pc = ax.contourf(data, levels=levels)  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'contourf'```

Comment: Typo above.  Swap ax and data in the zip output.

Comment: I fixed the typo